# “How to fix ‘Syntax Error Near’ error in BASH”

Tags: bash, shell, kubectl

I'm setting a new condition for run delete job if exist but don't work in production case.

GNU bash, v4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

```
docker run -e GO_DEPENDENCY_LABEL_PIPE='XXXXX' -e CREDENTIAL_NAME='production.XXXXX' -e KUBE_TOKEN='XXXXX' -v /go/pipelines/deploy-portal-site-data/helm:/helm --add-host=api.production.XXXXX:00.000.000.000 --rm -t --entrypoint /bin/bash docker.XXXXX.com.br/kubectl-prod:latest --login -c "kubectl config set-credentials production.XXXXX --token=XXXXX; VerifyJob=0; [[  -ge 1 ]] && kubectl -n production delete job portal-site-data-production || echo 'There is no job at the moment'"
```

I expect the output of clean job, but the actual output is

```
Creating /root/.helm/repository 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/cache 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/local 
Creating /root/.helm/starters 
Creating /root/.helm/cache/archive 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/repositories.yaml 
Adding stable repo with URL: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com 
Adding local repo with URL: http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts 
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /root/.helm.
Not installing Tiller due to 'client-only' flag having been set
Happy Helming!
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Skip local chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈ Happy Helming!⎈ 
"gfn-helm-repo" has been added to your repositories
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: conditional binary operator expected
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near `1'
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `kubectl config set-credentials production.XXXXX --token=XXXXX; VerifyJob=0; [[  -ge 1 ]] && kubectl -n production delete job portal-site-data-production || echo 'There is no job at the moment''
```

Comment: "[[ -ge 1 ]]". Looks like a parameter in the command isn't actually set.

Comment: you can put your script in https://www.shellcheck.net/# to see syntax errors

Answer (score 2):

```
[[  -ge 1 ]]
```

I think the error comes from this part of the command.

It is testing if "undefined" is greater or equal to 1

Answer (score 1):

I deleted my chart 
`helm delete portal-site-data-production --tiller-namespace production --purge`

and put \ before the "

```
set -x
docker pull $DOCKER_HELM_PROD_IMAGE
docker run \
-e GO_DEPENDENCY_LABEL_PIPE='${GO_DEPENDENCY_LABEL_PIPE}' \
-e CREDENTIAL_NAME='${CREDENTIAL_NAME}' \
-e KUBE_TOKEN='${KUBE_TOKEN}' \
-v $PWD/helm:/helm \
--add-host=api.production.XXXXX:00.000.000.000 \
--rm -t --entrypoint /bin/bash \
$DOCKER_HELM_PROD_IMAGE \
--login -c "kubectl config set-credentials ${CREDENTIAL_NAME} --token=${KUBE_TOKEN}; VerifyJob=$(kubectl -n production get job| grep -c portal-site-data-production); \"[[ ${VerifyJob} -ge 1 ]]\" && kubectl -n production delete job portal-site-data-production || echo \"There is no job at the moment\""
```

This Ok now, thank you very much to everyone.